# External iLogic rules in Forge

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

Is there a way for using external iLogic rules in combination with Forge Automation?
I've got an iLogic rule that depends on the following external iLogic rule:

```
AddVbFile "MyExternal_iLogicFile.iLogicVb"
```

I've added this file (MyiLogicFile.iLogicVb) to my bundle in the hope that Forge would resolve this, but no luck.

Therefore, my question is:

- Is it possible, at all, to use external iLogic rules?
- If is, how do I get them in Forge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and have just written a blog post about it: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/use-external-ilogic-rules

The main points are that the file resolution logic will be the same as on the desktop searching in these locations: [iLogic search path for custom references](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/2014/06/ilogic-search-path-for-custom-references.html)

So you can either:

a) Add the file to the folder where the relative path provided for **AddVbFile** would take you from the location of the Inventor file that references it

b) Set the paths in the Active Project being used so that Inventor can find it

c) Use the **iLogic Add-In**'s **Automation** interface to set the **ExternalRuleDirectories** property where the external VB file resides